# How to get symbol from securitylist using quickfix?

Tags: c#, .net, quickfix, fix-protocol

I'm sending a SecurityListRequest and I am receiving confirmation.  I am unable to get the symbol from the response. I'm getting response like this.

```
8=FIXT.1.1|9=795|35=y|34=3|49=TMATCH=YYYYY|52=20160804-09:39:56.534|56=zzzzz|320=0001|322=zzzz->zzzzx|393=19|560=0|893=Y|
  146=2|
    55=xxxxx|48=xxxxx|22=8|167=xxxx|762=PERIOD|15=xxx|423=1|20000=1W|
    55=xxxx|48=xxxxx|22=8|167=xxxx|762=PERIOD|15=xxx|423=1|20000=1M|
10=234
```

I tried to get like this

```
QuickFix.FIX50.SecurityList.NoRelatedSymGroup symbolGroup
  = new QuickFix.FIX50.SecurityList.NoRelatedSymGroup();

int noofsymbols = m.Get(new NoRelatedSym()).getValue();

symbolGroup.Get(new Symbol());
```

and

```
m.get(new symbol()).getvalue();
```

and

```
m.getfield(new stringfield(55));
```

Every time it is throwing exception saying "Field Not Found" for tag 55.

Comment: I fixed your grammar and message formatting so that I could actually read it.

Comment: Is this QuickFIX/n (native C#) or regular C++ QuickFIX with the crappy C# wrapper?

Comment: this is Quickfix/n (c#)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You created a new empty `NoRelatedSymGroup` object, but you forgot to populate it from your message.

I think you are using the C++ QF with the C# wrapper, so this is probably the code you'd want:

```
var sym1 = new Symbol();
var sym2 = new Symbol();

m.getGroup(1, symbolGroup); // first group
symbolGroup.get(sym1);

m.getGroup(2, symbolGroup); // second group
symbolGroup.get(sym2);
```

Comment: this is working fine for symbol,then how can i get userdefined tags form that group..... i tired like this but it is showing exception as field not defined for the tag 2000....var tenor = new StringField(20000);   symbolGroup.GetField(tenor);

Comment: The QF/n site has docs about how to extend your DD to accept custom fields.

Comment: If this answer helped you, please accept it as correct when you have a moment.